# сравнение дат из списка

Tags: java, arraylist

У меня есть список дат:

```
ArrayList<String> date = new ArrayList<String>();
```

и переменная в которой хранится сегодняшняя дата:

```
String formattedDate;
Date current = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");
formattedDate = df.format(current);
```

Но когда я пытаюсь проверить даты на равенство:
 `if (date.get(position) == formattedDate){}`, это не срабатывает, то есть даты не равны.
Подскажите как проверить даты

Comment: а вы форматируете список дат так же как и переменную `formattedDate`?

Comment: Если у вас они string проверяйте с помощью equals().